# The ViewData item with the key "KEY" is a "System.Int32" but must be of type 'IEnumerable <SelectListItem> "

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

The ViewData item with the key "roleID" is a "System.Int32" but must be of type 'IEnumerable  ".

I cant fix it 
**Please i need your help!!  This is my code:**

admin Model:

```
 [Key]
    public int adminID { get; set; }

    [DisplayName("Role")]
    public int roleID { get; set; }
    public virtual Role roles { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage ="Le nom est obligatoire.")]
    public string Nom { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Le prenom est obligatoire.")]
    public string Prenom { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "L'email est obligatoire.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^([a-zA-Z0-9_\-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$", ErrorMessage = "email n'est pas valide.")]
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
    [Remote("IsEmailAdminExist", "Admin", ErrorMessage = "URL exist!")]
    public virtual  string Email { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Le mot de pass est obligatoire.")]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Pass { get; set; }

    public string Photo { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public HttpPostedFileBase PhotoUpload{ get; set; }
```

role Model:

```
[Key]
public int roleID { get; set; }

[Required(ErrorMessage = "Le nom est obligatoire.")]
public string Nom { get; set; }

public virtual ICollection<Admin> Admins { get; set; }
```

Admin Controller:

GET :

```
// GET: Admin/Edit/5
            public ActionResult Edit(int id)
            {
                var data = from p in AdminContext.roles
                           select new
                           {
                               roleID = p.roleID,
                               roleNom = p.Nom
                           };

                SelectList list = new SelectList(data, "roleID", "roleNom");
                ViewBag.Roles = list;


                Admin admin = AdminContext.admins.Where(x => x.adminID == id).SingleOrDefault();
                if (admin != null)
                {
                    return View("~/Views/Administration/Admin/Edit.cshtml", admin);
                }
                else
                {
                    return HttpNotFound();
                }
            }
```

POST:

```
// POST: Admin/Edit/5
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Edit(Admin model)
        {
            Admin admin = AdminContext.admins.Where(x => x.adminID == model.adminID).SingleOrDefault();
            ModelState.Remove("Pass");
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                if (admin != null)
                {
                    if (model.PhotoUpload != null && model.PhotoUpload.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        var extension = Path.GetExtension(model.PhotoUpload.FileName);
                        var filename = model.adminID + extension;
                        var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Content/TemplateAdmin/assets/upload/admins"), filename);
                        model.PhotoUpload.SaveAs(path);
                        model.Photo = "/Content/TemplateAdmin/assets/upload/admins/" + filename;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        model.Photo = admin.Photo;
                    }
                    if (model.Pass == null && model.Pass != "")
                        model.Pass = admin.Pass;

                    AdminContext.Entry(admin).CurrentValues.SetValues(model);
                    AdminContext.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
            //tempdata
            return View("~/Views/Administration/Admin/Edit.cshtml", model);
        }
```

Edit View:

```
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label">
                                Role <span class="symbol required"></span>
                            </label>
                            @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.roleID, ViewBag.Roles as SelectList, "Selectioner un role", new { @class = "form-control search-select", id = "roleID" })
                        </div>
```

Comment: What is your POST action in controller?

Comment: I put it as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you don't repopulate your `SelectList` in POST action, so the view is returned to user without `SelectList`.

Repeat this code in POST action (or wrap it in a function for DRYness):

```
var data = from p in AdminContext.roles
            select new
            {
                roleID = p.roleID,
                roleNom = p.Nom
            };

SelectList list = new SelectList(data, "roleID", "roleNom");
ViewBag.Roles = list;
```

Comment: Thank you very much, the problem is solved

Comment: plz how can i get the name of roles in the index view , because i can just take  the roleID

Comment: That's a separate question. Make a helper method that converts your Id to Name and use it in view. Or make another model with string member for role name and fill it from controller with lync.

Comment: Thank you for responding